# How can I capture specific xmlhttprequests in Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing a firefox extension and want to capture the requests being sent out to a certain url.

I'm adding a listener to the event, `browser.webRequest.onCompleted` from a background script. Problem is that the listener only gets fired up if I add `<all_urls>` in the permissions section of the manifest and the urls option in the filter when adding the listener.

src/background.js:

```js
function saveData(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    saveData,
    {
        urls: ["<all_urls>"],
        types: ['xmlhttprequest']
    });
```

Manifest.json:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "LolEsports Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "storage"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["src/background.js"]
    }
}
```

Here's what I get:
[image: screenshot]

But if I change the manifest to:

```js
"permissions": [
     "https://prod-relapi.ewp.gg/persisted/gw/*",
     "webRequest",
     "webRequestBlocking",
     "storage"
 ]
```

and in background.js:

```js
browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    saveData,
    {
        urls: ["https://prod-relapi.ewp.gg/persisted/gw/*"],
        types: ['xmlhttprequest']
    });
```

nothing is shown in the console. What am I missing so that the listener is fired up on specific url patterns??

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you so much. It works now. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quoting MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest):

> To intercept resources loaded by a page (such as images, scripts, or stylesheets), the extension must have the host permission for the resource **as well as for the main page** requesting the resource. For example, if a page at "https://developer.mozilla.org" loads an image from "https://mdn.mozillademos.org", then an extension must have both host permissions if it is to intercept the image request.

[Quoting Chrome API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest):

> Starting from Chrome 72, an extension will be able to intercept a request only if it has host permissions to both the requested URL and **the request initiator**.

So you need to add `"https://watch.euw.lolesports.com/*"` in manifest's `"permissions"`.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that section in MDN. Once again, thank you.